# Cannot post php file - file upload

Tags: php, html, post, file-upload

I have the following files (html and php) and am able to run php on my server, and yet I keep getting "CANNOT POST /fileUpload.php when I click upload. Any ideas about whats going on would be appreciated. Thanks

(Upload.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="fileUpload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <!--<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="500"> -->
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

(fileUpload.php)

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the directory of fileUpload.php

And don't you want to have that moving process inside if(isset($_POST["submit"])) ?

Comment: Both the html file and the php file are the in same directory, with a folder called 'uploads' for the photos to go. Is this correct?

Comment: ok try instead of <form action="fileUpload.php"
this: <form action="/fileUpload.php"

Comment: unfortunately not. The guy underneath that commented said the code was working fine for him, so I'm not sure what could possibly be wrong

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine. I am able to upload JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files. Please check your file structure.

You can check the file destination path before upload by using file_exists() function

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php